# Help running cgminer on Ubuntu 14.04 - waiting for USB hotplug devices, and other errors

Tags: cgminer, ubuntu

I'm a total noob regarding bitcoin mining, I've installed cgminer using apt-get install but I can't get it to work.

I start it with this command:

```
./cgminer  -o stratum+tcp://www.albamine.net:3333 -u Weblogin.WorkerName -p WorkerPassword
```

I followed [these instructions](http://www.albamine.net/index.php?page=gettingstarted):  (I'm mining for scotcoin.)

> 1. Install Ubuntu
> 2. Install updates
>      `sudo apt-get update`
> 3. Install updates for your graphics card
> 4. Install misc packages
>      `sudo apt-get install gedit git libcurl4-openssl-dev libncurses5-dev pkg-config automake yasm`
> 5. Edit grub configuration
>      `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
>      Edit `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"`
>      `sudo update-grub`
> 6. Download [ATI OpenCL drivers](http://developer.amd.com/tools/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/#one). Untar it and run the script inside.
> 7. Reboot.
> 8. `git clone git://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer`
> 9. Download the [ADL SDK](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/display-library-adl-sdk/). Unzip it. Copy the include directory into cgminer, and name it ADL_SDK
> 10. Check dependencies for cgminer.
>       `cd ~/cgminer`
>       `./autogen.sh`
> 11. Create the build script:
>       `CFLAGS="-O2 -Wall -march=native -I /opt/AMDAPP/include/" LDFLAGS="-L/opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64" ./configure`
> 12. `make`
> 13. Run using
>       `export DISPLAY=:0; export GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS=1; ./cgminer -n`

The first few times I tried I got an error that repeatedly said:

```
KnC spiL Can not open SPI device /dev/spidev1.0: No such file or directory.
```

NowI'm getting a terminal that looks like this, and I have no idea. I've googled select sections of the code but can't figure out what it's all about. Any suggestions would be gratefully received. Thanks.

[image]

Info. Running Ubuntu 14:04 on a System 76 Galago Ultra pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system reports: Intel's new Iris Pro graphics.

As far as ubuntu 13.10 was concerned the package cgminer was compiled for nvidia graphics cards and installed the module for ubuntu.

Consider running a system with dedicated GPU w/ PCIe: e. g. nvidia and ATI and possibly compile cgminer by yourself.

I tried bfgminer for ubuntu now, see here: http://jarco.be/install-bfgminer-ubuntu-mint/

...but cannot get it to work for litecoin scrypt right now...

NOW up and running bfgminer compiled for ubuntu 14.04 with howto from here:
https://debianhelp.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/bitcoin-mining-in-ubuntu-with-bfgminer/

with some minor changes:

- installed "bitcoin-qt" instead of "bitcoin"
- `sudo apt-get install uthash-dev`
- `./autogen.sh && ./configure --enable-scrypt --enable-opencl && make`
- modified ".bfgminer/bfgminer.conf" can be pasted here, if you want
  -> 880kh/s @ ATI Radeon R9 290X

Comment: Oh I see, it looks like mining for scotcoins might be more involved than I'd expected. I'd hoped it would be the sort of thing I could've done using spare processing power when my laptop isn't busy! Thanks for enlightening me!

Comment: Furthermore the cgminer versions mentioned on your getting started page are outdated, there is only 4.x available. And these versions do not support GPU mining at all (Con Kolivas writes):
Q: What happened to CPU and GPU mining?
A: Their efficiency makes them irrelevant in the bitcoin mining world today
and the author has no interest in supporting alternative coins that are better
mined by these devices.

Comment: Here is the pastebin instructions in HTML format that you can use to install everything since the web site is no longer hosting that page. http://pastebin.com/S2r9cSeD